# Proper and understandable (visual) instructions for doing Siddhasana

Tags: yoga

I read instructions for doing Siddhasana from various sources.

Some sources do not contain instructions in detail and many sources do not contain figures to understand where to place the left heel and right heel. Most of the sources contain different terminology (perineum, anus, etc.,) to keep the left heel.

I want to do Siddhasana on my own without any guide. And I am confused to follow because of fundamental difference in instructions.

Where can I find proper instructions with diagrams (instead of the only terminology) to do Siddhasana by own? Or what are the instructions to do it by self?